# Помогите адаптировать sh под bat

Tags: android, bash, bat, adb

У меня есть скриптик sh

```
BuildNum=`adb shell dumpsys package my.pakage | grep versionCode | cut -d "=" -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 1`
echo versionCode установленного APK файла: $BuildNum
```

И под маком у меня всё хорошо работает, но мне надо это как-то сделать и в батнике, чтоб запускалось под виндой

Вот это:

```
set "BNum=adb shell dumpsys package my.pakage | grep versionCode | cut -d '=' -f 2 | cut -d' ' -f 1"
ECHO %BNum%
```

Результатов не даёт, оно просто закрывает командную строку и скрипт дальше не выполняется..

Помогите пожалуйста

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

В пакетных файлах нет такой конструкции как "выполнить команду и присвоить ее вывод переменной". А еще нет grep и cut...

Если нет желания исхитряться - можно убрать лишнее оформление:

```
adb shell dumpsys package my.pakage | find "versionCode"
```

В противном случае смотрите инструкцию к циклу for /f (for /?)

PS возможно, вам подойдет комплект программ MinGW - там и bash есть, и grep, и cut... Кстати, если вы используете git - то они все у вас уже установлены.

Comment: Но команда выполняется в консоли андроид девайса, там есть grep и cut) А вот то что нет "выполнить команду и присвоить ее вывод переменной" это печально(( Спасибо

Comment: @Qubique ну и зачем вам тогда батник? :-)

Comment: @Qubique однако, насколько мне известно, adb все-таки выполняется не на девайсе.

Comment: батнику скармливаем apk и obb файлики и он всё устанавливает на девайс)

Comment: если юзать adb shell то на девайсе

Comment: @Qubique не путайте. У вас на девайсе выполняется команда `dumpsys package my.pakage`. А вот `adb shell ... | grep ... | cut ...` выполняется на компьютере.

Comment: Прежде, чем давать подобные категоричные утверждения, ознакомтесь с языком. Он намного мощнее, чем кажется на первый взгляд. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting

Comment: @0andriy я знаю этот язык. Но, если вы считаете что знаете его лучше - найдите заявленную команду.

Comment: Не буду спорить с гуру.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%I IN ('adb shell "dumpsys package com.android.phone | grep versionCode="') DO SET BNUM=%%I
ECHO %BNUM%
ECHO %BNUM:~12%
```